# maximize the page to the bottom HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build my first HTML/CSS webpage, but it seems that I'm having a problum with maximizing the page to the bottom limit. I mean if the content is not huge, the footer comes up the the middle of the page, how can I solve this problem?

I have attached a snapshot.

[image]

Here's the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blogs</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    body{ margin-left:0 ;margin-right:0 ;margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0 ; }
    .design { padding: 0 ; margin:0 ;border: 0}
    .left_head  {background-image:url("images/header_left.gif"); }
    .header_center {background-image: url("images/header_center.gif");background-repeat:repeatx;}
    .right_head {background-image: url("images/header_right.gif");}
    table { margin-left:0 ;margin-right:0 ;margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; padding: 0 ; border: 0; cellpadding: 0 ; cellspacing: 0 }
    table td { margin:0 ; padding: 0 ; border: 0; cellpadding: 0 ; cellspacing: 0 }
    .left_body {background-image: url("images/blogs_22.gif");background-repeat:repeaty;}
    .right_body {background-image: url("images/blogs_25.gif");background-repeat:repeaty;}
    .left_footer  {background-image:url("images/footer_left.gif"); }
    .right_footer  {background-image:url("images/footer_right.gif"); }
    .footer_center {background-image: url("images/footer_center.gif");background-repeat:repeatx; color: white; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 12px}
    h1 { color:#abbb2d; font-family: tahoma; padding-left: 10px}
    p { font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14px}
    .welcome { font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold} 
    .menu { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding:0 ; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 14px; }
    a { color: gray; text-decoration: none} 
    a:hover { color: #abbb2d; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold}
    .menu_cell {background-color: #dce6ca; }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body height="100%">
    <table class="design" width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td class="left_head" width="42" height="153"></td>
    <td class="header_center" ><img src="images/logo.gif" width="258" height="140" alt="Blogs logo"></td>
    <td class="right_head" width="43" height="153"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="left_body" width="42" height="100%"></td>
    <td class="center_body">
    <table center_table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td class="menu_cell"width="10%" height="100%">
    <ul class="menu" >
    <li><a href="home.html"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html"> About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html"> Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html"> Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>

    </td>
    <td width="90%">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <hr>
    <p class="welcome"> Welcome to my first HTML & CSS website.</p> 
    <p>This is an assignment assigned by Dr. Jameleddine Hussaine, Web Development & Engineering course at King Fahd University. </p>
    <p>* You can either navigate my website through the left navigation bar or the using the linke at the top. </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td class="right_body" width="43" height="100%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr  class="footer" valign="bottom">
    <td class="left_footer" width="42" height="84"></td>
    <td class="footer_center" >All copyright reserved &copy; Hamad Alkathiri <br/> King Fahad University for Petroluem & Minerals</td>
    <td class="right_footer" width="43" height="84"></td>
    </tr>


    </table>
    </body>


    </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Screenshots are handy, but this is like showing us a picture of your car and telling us it won't start and asking why. CODE PLEASE!

Comment: I'm sorry, I just uploaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html, body { height: 100%; }` and you should [look at this](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it but it did not work. I attached the code will you check it out for me please?

Comment: Oh, you're using a table. Then add the table to that declaration. `html, body, table { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a min-height to your container or your body.

```
#container {
    min-height:100%;
}
```